# Cartopy figsize does not change the actual size of the map

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, cartopy

How to change the figure width and height when using cartoopy. figsize change only the white space around the figure, yet not the figure itself. Any ideas.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 45], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this code is found [here](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-features-py)
[image]

Comment: A couple of steps in Cartopy will do. But not a single statement like Basemap.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Your question has changed. My comment above is now invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the map can be only defined by its extent through the `set_extent()` method. Changing the `figsize` will only affect the white frame around the map axes.

**EDIT**

I see only one option if you want to **enlarge the map without changing its extent**: change the projection. Some examples here:

[image] [image] [image]

As you can see, some projection will tend to increase the height, some other will appear wider. You cannot fully control the width/height ratio of the map, but still you can try to see if some projections are better for you.

You can find a list of projection at https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html.

Here is the code that produced the first image:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.LambertCylindrical())
ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 45])
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.set_title('LambertCylindrical')

plt.savefig('LambertCylindrical.png', dpi=100)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am trying to plot only tropical region, yet I want also to enlarge the map without going beyond the tropical area. Is there is any way to enlarge specific domain without increasing the latitude and longitude extension?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that Cartopy has some argument like width and height in the basemap function(http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap.html) that controls the width and height of the image. I think that it will be nice if Cartopy has similar capabilities. Thanks

Comment: See the following for more comprehensive solution. https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1074